# Как сделать так чтобы программа на python сама вводила текст? И ещё вопрос: Как сделать так чтобы программа на Python сама нажимала на кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как сделать так чтобы программа на python сама вводила текст? И ещё вопрос: Как сделать так чтобы программа на Python сама нажимала на кнопки?

Comment: В чем ваш конкретный вопрос? Какие способы вы уже попробовали? Ознакомьтесь со справокй о том, [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью библиотек, таких как "pydirectinput" или "pyautogui". И подобных, их огромное количество

Comment: WTFisGoingOn, спасибо за ответ, сейчас смотрю эти библиотеки, много нужных вещей нашёл. Благодарю за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть прекрасная библиотека pyautogui.

Тут примеры
https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#examples

Comment: а также pyinpyt